# Keep changes to defaultWorkingDirectory thoughout stages within Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML file that resembles the following:

```
stages: 
  - stage: A
    pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-2019'  
    jobs:
    - job: a
      steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |              
             #edits file "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myfolder/myfile.json"

  - stage: B
    dependsOn: A
    pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-2019'  
    jobs:
      - job: b
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |              
             #uses file "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myfolder/myfile.json"
```

I have split my pipeline into two stages; A: edits a file in a repository and B: works with the edited file.

My problem is, the files seem to get reset between stages. Is there any way of keeping the changes throughout the stages, rather than resetting them?

I don't want to publish artifacts and so on as in stage b, although not in the YAML above, I am running multiple PowerShell script files that contain hardcoded file paths and it would just be a mess overwriting the file paths to point at the artifacts directory before running the stage.

An

Answer (score 2):

Based on my test , the cause of this issue is that the two stages run on the different Agent machines.

For example: Stage A -> Agent machine name: 'fv-az146' , Stage B -> Agent machine name: 'fv-az151'

You could check the agent information in **Build log -> Initialize job**.

[image: Initialize job]

> Is there any way of keeping the changes throughout the stages, rather
>   than resetting them?

Since you don't want to publish artifacts, you could try to use [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to run two stages.

You need to add demands to the agent to ensure that the stages run on the same Self-hosted agent.

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#demands):

> The demands keyword is supported by private pools.

We couldn't specify specific "Agent Capabilities" in Microsoft-hosted agents. So we couldn't ensure that two stages can run on the same agent

**Update:**

Since the two stages are running on the same agent, the "check out" step in Stage B could override the files in Stage A.

So you also need to add the `- checkout: none` in Stage B.

Here is the updated Yaml template:

```
stages:      
 - stage: A
    pool:
     name: Pool name
     demands:
     - Agent.Name -equals agentname1
    jobs:
    - job: a
      steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          ...

  - stage: B
    dependsOn: A
    pool:
     name: Pool name
     demands:
     - Agent.Name -equals agentname1
    jobs:
      - job: b
        steps:
        - checkout: none
        - task: PowerShell@2
        ...
```

The overall workflow： the Stage A edits the files and save it to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).

Then Stage B could directly use the files in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).

The files in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) will keep changes in Stage A and B.

Comment: do jobs use different processes in the same way as stages? Or do changes in jobs stay until the stage is completed?

Comment: @thatOneGuy, I have updated the answer. You could check it. If you have any suggestions, please feel free to  let me know